# Filebeat not harvesting logs

Tags: logging, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am trying to setup filebeat and logstash on my **server1** and send data to elasticsearch located on **server2** and visualize it using kibana.

Following are filebeat logs and when i run ***filebeat test output*** it showed the result as show in image bleow.

[image]

As you can observer, filbeat is not harvesting logs at all

```
2020-07-10T07:40:14.852Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:40:14.852Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:40:14.852Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:40:24.853Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:40:24.853Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:40:24.853Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:40:34.853Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:40:34.853Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:40:34.853Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:40:44.828Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20},"total":{"ticks":170,"time":{"ms":4},"value":170},"user":{"ticks":150,"time":{"ms":4}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1024},"open":7},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"4f97f60d-b9f4-451c-b9f2-1935988798b1","uptime":{"ms":840027}},"memstats":{"gc_next":10220512,"memory_alloc":5959576,"memory_total":24826152},"runtime":{"goroutines":21}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.03,"15":0.08,"5":0.06,"norm":{"1":0.015,"15":0.04,"5":0.03}}}}}}
2020-07-10T07:40:44.853Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:40:44.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:40:44.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:40:54.856Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:40:54.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:40:54.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:41:04.856Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:41:04.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:41:04.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:41:14.828Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:145  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":20},"total":{"ticks":180,"time":{"ms":8},"value":180},"user":{"ticks":160,"time":{"ms":8}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1024},"open":7},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"4f97f60d-b9f4-451c-b9f2-1935988798b1","uptime":{"ms":870027}},"memstats":{"gc_next":10216448,"memory_alloc":5117872,"memory_total":25101640},"runtime":{"goroutines":21}},"filebeat":{"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":0.02,"15":0.08,"5":0.05,"norm":{"1":0.01,"15":0.04,"5":0.025}}}}}}
2020-07-10T07:41:14.856Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:41:14.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:41:14.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:41:24.856Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:41:24.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:41:24.856Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
2020-07-10T07:41:34.857Z    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:141  Run input
2020-07-10T07:41:34.857Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:191    Start next scan
2020-07-10T07:41:34.857Z    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:212    input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0
```

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/nomi/unity/media/*.log

output.logstash:
  enabled: true
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\|%{GREEDYDATA:module}\|%{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
  }
  date {
    locale => "en"
    match => [ "timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    timezone => "America/New_York"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elk_server_ip:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "blend_test" 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

Comment: Can you exec: "ls -l - /home/mahesh/Documents/refactor/nomi/unity/media/*.log", please?

Comment: @VíctorOriol its `-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu `

Comment: Is it possible that the file is empty?

Comment: @VíctorOriol, I have checked many times.... log file is not empty...it is continuously receiving logs. do you think it has something to do with the folder permissions?
currently,the folder has **drwxrwxr-x**....is this permission fine (or) should I change it to **drwxr-xr-x** ?

Comment: Nice! I was just asking to go over all the points. Now, it is possible for you, change your filebeat output, to "output.console" and restart the service? the goal is to make sure that filebeat is treating the logs well, then we will focus on logstash, but first it is important to see that filebeat is treating the logs

Comment: @VíctorOriol I am not sure while logs are shown but to my surprise, logstash is receving all the logs in real time which is excatly what i want

Comment: Good news then, sometimes: https://media.giphy.com/media/12NUbkX6p4xOO4/giphy.gif helps! jajajaaaaa

Answer (score 0):

The reason that filebeat is not harvesting the logs because of the following reason:

**data.json in the registry folder `${Filebeat_Homepath}/data/registry/filebeat/data.json` may not be empty that means log file has been already parsed on first or consecutive scan.**

You can delete the contents in **data.json** file and then start the filebeat again.

Hope this might solve your issue.

Comment: my **data.json** is empty.... although i have deleted registry folder and restarted filbeat with **filebeat -e -d "*"** , still no luck, filebeat is not receiving logs but registry folder got created automatically when i restarted. I could have also restarted with **systemctl** command but since I want to see the logs , I have used above command. Please suggest if I am going in the right direction?

Comment: hi @Mahesh, would you be able to solve your problem? I've faced the same behaviour